# Browser debug: how to see what Javascript functions was called after some action?

Tags: javascript, debugging, browser, dom-events

Maybe Firebug or Opera, Google Chrome tools allows it. Where to find it? how to use?

Example: I click the button and want to see what Javascript code fired up after that action.

Answer (score 23):

In Google Chrome, you can open Developer Tools (Ctrl+Shift+J)

Choose Profiles tab, choose Collect JavaScript CPU Profile, click Start

When finish, click Stop and see the progress log...

Comment: The same thing in Firebug can be found through Console tab, Profile (click to start, click again to see report).

Comment: Thanks, works... a little confusing. But ok :) better to watch in tree mode http://www.zimagez.com/zimage/screenshot-04072012-094707pm.php

Comment: BTW it's possible to debug events like mouse click or timer tick with google chrome. See screenshot http://www.zimagez.com/zimage/screenshot-04102012-070517am.php

Answer (score 0):

you can include firebug lite in your html .. that will enable you to debug javascript ..you can get it from here : http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Comment: right:) if i want to track unknown function inside stranger code.

Comment: best thing I would say is to put a breakpoint in the initial stage ie when the first function is getting called and just flow through the code or you can always use profile mode of firebug

Comment: It is possible to set breakpoints on events - like mouse click. Screenshot from Google Chrome http://www.zimagez.com/zimage/screenshot-04102012-070517am.php